# Overriding css/sass rules in an Angular project

Tags: css, angular, sass

How can I override material's css?

I have this in the `index.html` file

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have got this in `style.scss` but none of classes in material.scss override material's css but it doesn't work.

```
@import "material";
```

Comment: 'material'.scss override 'material's css ?? Can you please reframe your question..